# .htaccess SEO friendly URL with queryString

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, seo

I have a page like:

```
page.php?mode=dashboard&hl=en
```

and i want to use like:

```
site.com/dashboard?hl=en
```

how must i use RewriteRule? Thanks...

**EDIT:** I think this is not possible with .htaccess. Need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

wish it helps you

```
# Redirect /Category.php?Category_Id=10&Category_Title=some-text
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Category_Id=(\d+)&Category_Title=([\w-]+)$
RewriteRule ^Category\.php$ /Category/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this gives site.com/bla/foo type link. But i need site.com/bla?hl=foo type link.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this code in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?mode=([^\s&]+)&(hl=[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w-]+)/?$ page.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```